# Elixir Slime - Embed Elixir in Javascript Tag

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

If I have an assigns variable, how can I pass that to the Javascript tag? The following would work in Ruby Slim, but does not seem to in Elixir's Slime.

```
javascript:
  window.currentUser = { username: @username }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject a value using `#{}`:

```
javascript:
  window.currentUser = { username: #{username} }
```

You'll probably want to JSON encode the variable so that strings are inserted as double quoted escaped JavaScript strings. With `Poison`, you can do:

```
javascript:
  window.currentUser = { username: #{Poison.encode!(username)} }
```

If `username` is the string `foo`, the first one will render to:

```
<script>window.currentUser = { username: foo }</script>
```

while the second one will render to:

```
<script>window.currentUser = { username: "foo" }</script>
```

Comment: In my case Elixir escaped HTML entities in the JSON string, so I had to additionally [unescape them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34064434/2750743)